# Double integral over normal pdf gives inconsistent answer

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am using `Integrate` function to do the following double integral

```
Integrate[3.1 x^2.1 Exp[-y^2/2]/(2 π)^0.5, {y, -1, 3}, {x, 0, y + 35}]
```

The result is 1204.63.

When I check with the following integral

```
N[Integrate[Integrate[3.1 x^2.1, {x, 0, y + 35}, Assumptions :> y ∈ Reals]*
   Exp[-y^2/2]/(2 π)^0.5, {y, -1, 3}]]
```

The result is 52774.4, which also agrees with what I got in Matlab. I thought the first one is a nice and clean way to do double integral than the second one, but it seems that the result is not what I want if the function w.r.t. x (`x^2.1` in this case) does not have integer power.

I would be very thankful if anyone can answer my question.

Comment: `NIntegrate[3.1 x^2.1 Exp[-y^2/2]/(2 \[Pi])^0.5, {y, -1, 3}, {x, 0, y + 35}]` is perhaps a nice compromise.  `Integrate` is primarily for exact computation. It tries with inexact input, but in this case fails.  Note that, with exact input, `N@Integrate[31/10 x^(21/10) Exp[-y^2/2]/(2 \[Pi])^(1/2), {y, -1, 3}, {x, 0, y + 35}]` also gives the right answer.

Comment: BTW, you don't seem to be asking a question.  No "?" for example.  Just observations about the behavior of `Integrate`.  It's not clear whether you want an explanation or other workarounds or what.

Comment: Switch `Integrate` to `NIntegrate`. It seems that the machine precision values in your expression make it impossible to get the correct answer symbolically when posed in this way.

Comment: Thanks Michael And Oleksandr very much for your comment, it resolves my concern definitely! Sorry for being unable to make the question clear. I was using the first expression a lot to get numerical experiments without noticing the existence problem of inconsistency like this. I thought the second one is correct because it got the same result with Matlab, I was just stuck in the confusion and unable to figure out the problem with the first expression. BTW, when the power of x is integer instead of 2.1 in this case, the results of both expressions always agree. Thanks again :)

Comment: Related (perhaps a duplicate?): http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51809/function-given-exact-arguments-returns-hugely-different-value-than-it-returns-wh

Comment: Only two of the following get an accurate answer.  It's hard to track down what exactly goes wrong, but the upshot is simple: Use `NIntegrate` to get an approximate numerical answer --  
``Integrate[31/10 x^2 Exp[-y^2/2]/(2 π)^(1/2), {y, -1, 3}, {x, 0, y + 35.}]``
``Integrate[31/10 x^2 Exp[-y^2/2]/(2 π)^(1/2), {y, -1, 3}, {x, 0., y + 35}]``
``Integrate[31/10 x^2. Exp[-y^2/2]/(2 π)^(1/2), {y, -1, 3}, {x, 0, y + 35}]``
``Integrate[31/10 x^2 Exp[-y^2/2]/(2 π)^(1/2), {y, -1, 3}, {x, 0, y + 35.`20}]``
``Integrate[31/10 x^2 Exp[-y^2/2]/(2 π)^(1/2), {y, -1, 3}, {x, 0, y + 35.`200}]``

Answer (score 1):

This does not answer the question *why* but I post for interest.
The region of integration:

```
ir = ImplicitRegion[0 < x < y + 35 && -1 < y < 3, {x, y}];
RegionPlot[ir]
```

[image]

The integral must be < `Area[ir]f[38,0]`:369981. (not a helpful bound).  $0<x<38 \land -1<y<3$ would be a closer.

```
SetAttributes[dis, HoldFirst];
dis[u_] := {Style[#, Bold], ReleaseHold[#]} & @ HoldForm @ u;
f[x_, y_] := 3.1 x^2.1 Exp[-y^2/2]/(2 π)^0.5;
r1 = dis[NIntegrate[f[x, y], {y, -1, 3}, {x, 0, 35 + y}]];
r2 = dis[NIntegrate[f[x, y], {x, 0, 38}, {y, -1, 3}]];
r3 = dis[NIntegrate[f[x, y], {x, y} ∈ ir]];
r4 = dis[Integrate[f[x, y], {x, y} ∈ ir]]
Grid[{r1, r2, r3,r4}, Alignment -> Left, Frame -> All]
```

As has been observed by MichaelE2 and OleksandrR numerical integration yields correct result. Interestingly, `Integrate` works with region (presumably switching to numerical integration). The results are summarized below:

[image]

Comment: Yes, the last two entries are effectively equivalent.  `Integrate` over a region will call `NIntegrate` with `WorkingPrecision` set to the minimum precision of the integrand and region, when the precision is less than infinity.